# backtrace function only got the last frame

Tags: c, gdb, mips

I want to call backtrace function to get the callchain, the following is my code, this code works good on x86, but can't work on mips

```
gcc -o hello-x86 hello.c -g -rdynamic -O0 -Wall
./hello-x86
size = 6
0x40095c : ./hello-x86(foo+0x1f) [0x40095c]
0x400a2d : ./hello-x86(b+0x9) [0x400a2d]
0x400a38 : ./hello-x86(a+0x9) [0x400a38]
0x400a4e : ./hello-x86(main+0x14) [0x400a4e]
0x7fee0d003f45 : /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fee0d003f45]
0x400879 : ./hello-x86() [0x400879]
```

but on mips, just only got the last frame, how to fix it ?

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -o hello hello.c -g -rdynamic -O0 -Wall -msoft-float -EL
./hello
size = 1
0x400a04 : ./hello(foo+0x24) [0x400a04]
```

can't get b and a and main. but i can got full callchain in gdb, why can't got it via backtrace function ?
my toolchain is codesourcery mips-2016.05, the libc version is 2.23

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <execinfo.h>

#define BACKTRACE_SIZ 100

int i = 0;

void foo(void)
{
    void *array[BACKTRACE_SIZ];
    size_t size, i;
    char **strings;

    size = backtrace(array, BACKTRACE_SIZ);
    strings = backtrace_symbols(array, size);

    printf("size = %ld\n", (long)size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%p : %s\n", array[i], strings[i]);
    }

    free(strings);

    while (1) {
        i++;
    }
}

void b(void)
{
    foo();
}

void a(void)
{
    b();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

i tried -fno-omit-frame-pointer and -fomit-frame-pointer, these two option all can't work.

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -o hello hello.c -g -rdynamic -O0 -Wall -msoft-float -EL -fomit-frame-pointer
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -o hello hello.c -g -rdynamic -O0 -Wall -msoft-float -EL -fno-omit-frame-pointer
```

and i tried on my arm board, it worse, the size is 0 on arm

Comment: Try adding `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` ? (May not make any difference at `-O0` but probably worth a try anyway.)

Comment: -fno-omit-frame-pointer or -fomit-frame-pointer, all can't work.

Comment: my problem resolved, the compile option must use -funwind-tables and -rdynamic together